# How to do a RewriteRule when the folder name is equal to an existing file name?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Given the following Folder "de":

```
.
..
index.php
faq.php
```

If I try to fire a RewriteRule from my .htaccess (in the parent directory) like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^de/test/ de/faq.php [NC,L]
```

... it works totally fine, but if I try it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^de/faq/ de/faq.php [NC,L]
```

then the Apache returns a "404 Not found" instead of firing the RewriteRule.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

If MultiViews is enabled, it will try to search for similar files and folders hence why the rule doesn't work, when you disable it, it stops doing that which is why it works.

For a more in-depth investigation, you may enable your `RewriteLog` within your web server:

```
RewriteLog "/some/path/to/file/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

This way you can see how it behaviors and what it looks for when MultiViews is enabled and disabled.